# Converting HTTP request to cURL expression

Tags: java, http, curl

Is there a Java library that will convert instances of the following classes

```
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
```

into cURL expression?

That would be something that Chrome browser provides as *copy as cURL* option.

We're writing end-to-end automate test and logging cURL expressions would help us investigate problems and repeat single request easily.